# Excel: Conditional Formatting on another cell date, but within a given range

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

We have a project where we need to have carry out a task 35 days before it's start date.

The current excel solution has a cell with which is either, ("Yes, or "No"), with a another cell with the Start Date (formatted as a date), on the same row.

I currently use this formula to conditionally format the cell.

=AND(A1<>"Yes",A2,TODAY()+35)

This is OK, but it formats **every** cell greater than 35 days away, that has anything but "Yes" in the cell.

What I actually need is the formatting only to happen when the date is less than 35 days away, but not greater than 35 days away.

It's probably simple...but I just can't see it.

Comment: I think you could just do `=Today()-A1<35`, I think. (If `A1` has your date).

Comment: @BruceWayne Because the due date which we are assuming is A1, is in the future, it will be larger than Today()  as such I think you need to swap your TOday() and A1 around to get `(A1-Today())<35`

Comment: In one Bruce....thanks very much.